# Building railway timetable

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I am hoping to build a railway time table using asp.net web api & sql server database.

Below is the sample db design of the time table. I used this query to try out finding algorithm for the time table.

My current problem is when i try source and destination `[A-B]` it also reruns `[B-A]` results also. Still I haven't consider the time factor. Also your valuable suggestion appreciated.

Expected Output :

[image: expected output]

[image: expected output]

**I also have Geo Location of the halts..**

```
   DECLARE @Souce INT  =  2 , @Destination INT = 11


DECLARE @Routes TABLE(
    ID INT,
    RouteStart VARCHAR(MAX),
    RouteStop VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @TrainTimeTable TABLE( 
    ID              INT,
    RoutID          INT,
    Sequance        INT, -- determine the next station of the same route
    BeforeStation   INT,
    CurrentStation  INT,
    [Arr.Time]      TIME,
    [Dep.Time]      TIME
)

DECLARE @Halts TABLE(

    ID INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(MAX)
)



INSERT INTO @Routes VALUES  (1,'A','B'),
                            (2,'B', 'C'),
                            (3,'B', 'A');

INSERT INTO @Halts VALUES   (1,'A1'),
                            (2,'A2'),
                            (3,'A3'),
                            (4,'A4'),
                            (5,'A5'),
                            (6,'A6'),
                            (7,'B1'),
                            (8,'B2'),
                            (9,'B3'),
                            (10,'B4'),
                            (11,'B5'),
                            (12,'B6');

/*A To B*/
INSERT @TrainTimeTable VALUES   (1,1,1,1,1,'06:00','6:01'),
                                (2,1,2,1,2,'6:05' ,'6:06'),
                                (3,1,3,2,3,'6:10' ,'6:11'),
                                (4,1,4,3,4,'6:15' ,'6:16'),
                                (5,1,5,4,5,'6:20' ,'6:21'),
                                (6,1,6,5,6,'6:25' ,'6:25'); -- Stops here



/*B To C*/
INSERT @TrainTimeTable VALUES   (7,2,1,6,6,'6:30','6:31'),
                                (8,2,2,6,7,'6:35','6:36'),
                                (9,2,3,7,8,'6:40','6:41'),
                                (10,2,4,8,9,'6:45','6:46'),
                                (11,2,5,9,10,'6:50','6:51'),
                                (12,2,6,10,11,'7:00','7:01'),
                                (13,2,7,11,12,'7:10','7:10'); -- stops here

/*B to A*/
INSERT @TrainTimeTable VALUES   (14,3,1,6,6,'06:00','6:01'),
                                (15,3,2,6,5,'6:05' ,'6:06'),
                                (16,3,3,5,4,'6:10' ,'6:11'),
                                (17,3,4,4,3,'6:15' ,'6:16'),
                                (18,3,5,3,2,'6:20' ,'6:21'),
                                (19,3,6,2,1,'6:25' ,'6:25'); -- Stops here

SELECT  tc.*,
        hl1.Name AS 'BeforeName', 
        hl2.Name AS 'CurrentName', 
        rr.RouteStart + ' - '+rr.RouteStop AS 'Route' 
FROM @TrainTimeTable  tc
INNER JOIN @Routes rr ON rr.ID = tc.RoutID
INNER JOIN @Halts hl1 ON hl1.ID = tc.BeforeStation
INNER JOIN @Halts hl2 ON hl2.ID = tc.CurrentStation
WHERE tc.CurrentStation BETWEEN @Souce AND @Destination
```

Comment: Can you include what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Expected result please.

Comment: can you explain your table schema and how is it related to other tables

Comment: @Xedni Question updated.

Comment: @Sami - Question updated

Comment: @Squirrel - Routes holds summary of the time table, for an example Train that departs from A - C and depature time from A , arrival time to C and train name may be. It is only a trip summary.  Halts are train stations (Master File). TrainTimeTable  is the actual route, to travel A-C it has to stop Halts Like A, A1, A2, A3,  B1, B3, C .. I tried my best to explain, Hope it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT  tc.*,
        hl1.Name AS 'BeforeName', 
        hl2.Name AS 'CurrentName', 
        rr.RouteStart + ' - '+rr.RouteStop AS 'Route' 
FROM @TrainTimeTable  tc
INNER JOIN @Routes rr ON rr.ID = tc.RoutID
LEFT JOIN @Halts hl1 ON hl1.ID = tc.BeforeStation
LEFT JOIN @Halts hl2 ON hl2.ID = tc.CurrentStation
WHERE tc.CurrentStation BETWEEN @Souce AND @Destination
AND tc.RoutID < 3;
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| ID | RoutID | Sequance | BeforeStation | CurrentStation | Arr.Time | Dep.Time | BeforeName | CurrentName | Route |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
|  2 |      1 |        2 |             1 |              2 | 06:05:00 | 06:06:00 | A1         | A2          | A - B |
|  3 |      1 |        3 |             2 |              3 | 06:10:00 | 06:11:00 | A2         | A3          | A - B |
|  4 |      1 |        4 |             3 |              4 | 06:15:00 | 06:16:00 | A3         | A4          | A - B |
|  5 |      1 |        5 |             4 |              5 | 06:20:00 | 06:21:00 | A4         | A5          | A - B |
|  6 |      1 |        6 |             5 |              6 | 06:25:00 | 06:25:00 | A5         | A6          | A - B |
|  7 |      2 |        1 |             6 |              6 | 06:30:00 | 06:31:00 | A6         | A6          | B - C |
|  8 |      2 |        2 |             6 |              7 | 06:35:00 | 06:36:00 | A6         | B1          | B - C |
|  9 |      2 |        3 |             7 |              8 | 06:40:00 | 06:41:00 | B1         | B2          | B - C |
| 10 |      2 |        4 |             8 |              9 | 06:45:00 | 06:46:00 | B2         | B3          | B - C |
| 11 |      2 |        5 |             9 |             10 | 06:50:00 | 06:51:00 | B3         | B4          | B - C |
| 12 |      2 |        6 |            10 |             11 | 07:00:00 | 07:01:00 | B4         | B5          | B - C |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But How can we determine when I pick source and destination from a simple ui not to include route 3. For an example think if there is an another router C < B... Why Left Join to Halts?. Halts are always there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this predicate to end of the where clause.

```
AND tc.ID <= (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @TrainTimeTable WHERE CurrentStation =  @Destination ORDER BY ID)
```

Comment: According to your sample data, you should cut your sequence  at the destination point. I updated the script.